# Using a Google form/spreadsheet, is it possible to automate the creation of a group with an approval field?

Tags: workflow, google-groups

If it is possible to create a group after spreadsheet data has been collected and approved via workflow? If so, does anyone have a script that will do this?  Are you willing to share code?

Google Apps:   Google Groups for Business